# Amazon S3 WebDAV access

Tags: amazon-s3, webdav

I would like to access my Amazon S3 buckets without third-party software, but simply through the WebDAV functionality available in most operating systems. Is there a way to do that ? It is important to me that no third-party software is required.

Answer (score 5):

There's a number of ways to do this. I'm not sure about your situation, so here they are:
**Option 1: Easiest:**
 You can use a 3rd party "cloud gateway" provider, like http://storagemadeeasy.com/CloudDav/

**Option 2: Set up your own "cloud gateway" server**

- Set up a dedicated server or virtual server to act as a gateway. Using Amazon's own EC2 would be a good choice.
- Set up software that mounts S3 as a drive. Two I know of on Windows: (1) CloudBerry Drive http://www.cloudberrylab.com/ and (2) WebDrive (http://webdrive.com). For Linux, I have never done it, but you can try: https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse
- Set up a webdav server like CrushFTP. (It comes to mind because it's stable and cheap and works on any OS.) Another option is IIS but I personally find it's harder to set up securely for webdav.
- Set up a user in your WebDav server (ie CrushFTP or IIS) with access to the mapped S3 drive.
- **Possible snag:** Assuming you're using Windows, to start your services automatically and have this work, you may need to set up both services to use the same Windows user account (Services->(Your Service)->[right-click]Properties->Log On tab). This is because the S3 mapping software might not map the S3 drive for all Windows users. Alternatively, you can use FireDaemon if you get stuck on this step to start the programs as a service all under the same username.

**Other notes:** I have experience using WebDrive under pretty heavy loads, and it seems to work well. Under tons of pounding (I'm talking thousands of files per hour being added to a 5 TB WebDrive) it started to crash Windows. But I'm not sure if you are going that far with it. Also, if you're using EC2, you may not have that issue since it was likely caused by a huge transfer queue in memory and EC2 will have faster transit to S3 and keep the queue smaller.

Comment: s3fs-fuse works quite well for me and the overhead is low.

Comment: @JoeMornin Sorry for digging up an ancient thread. Did you get this working successfully with WebDav? I've setup s3fs which mounts my S3 bucket to the filesystem without a problem, but Apache is refusing to access it.

Comment: @pr.lwd Nope. I just used s3fs-fuse to mount the bucket. I didn't touch WebDAV.

Comment: @JoeMornin thanks for replying - only just noticed it(!). I got it going eventually, but we've ditched s3fs-fuse now anyway

Answer (score 0):

I finally gave up on this idea and today I use Rclone (https://rclone.org) to synchronize my files between AWS S3 and different computers. Rclone has the ability to mount remote storage on a local computer, but I don't use this feature. I simply use the `copy` and `sync` commands.

Answer (score -1):

S3 does not support webdav, so you're out of luck!

Also, S3 does not support hierarchial name spaces, so you cant directly map a filesystem onto it

There is an example java project here for putting a webdav server over Amazon S3 - https://github.com/miltonio/milton-aws