# Possible to Use FTP With Amazon S3/Google Drive/ OneDrive?

Tags: c#, ftp, amazon-s3, google-drive-api, onedrive

I have some websites that I backup daily, right now I have go every day to my ftp to grab the backup and then upload it to Google Drive.

I was looking at Amazon S3 and was hoping that maybe it would have ftp access to upload files but I am not seeing it.

My Control Panel has a schedule option to tranfer files on my server to another server through ftp. I would like to make use of this somehow but can't find anything that will allow this.

Otherwise can I write some sort of C# web app on a schedule to access my hosting companies ftp and then transfer it somehow to one of these storage providers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "cloud gateway" services like:
https://cloudgates.net/
http://storagemadeeasy.com/CloudFTP/
http://www.ftp2cloud.com/

Or, set up your own gateway server using WebDrive to map S3, and FileZilla Server. For details you can see my post here:
[Amazon S3 WebDAV access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257349/amazon-s3-webdav-access)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a direct GDrive/DropBox solution.  I'm also surprised there's no lazy solution for a free ftp host.  Windows azure offers a ftp server "FTP connector" that's fairly easy to turn on at:
https://portal.azure.com

You can get a free 1 GB account by selecting "View All" machine types during your deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Total Commander is perfect for that and I've been using it for 19 years and Google Drive with TC for 1 year.

1. You can download and install Total Commander free of charge from the official website ghisler.com  *Licensed or unlicensed allows you to use in 2 ways. If you choose to use it without a license, it will ask you to choose 1, 2 or 3 on the screen that appears each time you open the application.*
2. Open TC and enter the Options section from the Configurations menu
3. Click the Download button in the Add-ons section. The Plugins page on the official website of the TC. ghisler.com/plugins.htm If you search Google Drive on this page, you will find the plug-in named Cloud. (Version 2.1 is now available for download.)
4. If you open the zip file with Total Commander after downloading the zip file, the required files are extracted to the plugins folder of TC automatically.

**The plugin is installed. Now in the queue settings**

1. [Select Network Neighborhood on TC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxZcP.png)
2. [Click the Cloud folder that opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrpJl.png)
3. [You will see F7 = new connection.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiZAP.png)
4. [Press F7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl6us.png)
5. [Type your connection a name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D83bY.png)
6. [Select the connection type from the pop-up window (DropBox, Google Drive, One Drive, Yandex Drive, and Microsoft Azure Data Lake) and enter your information.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlFAd.png) [Type the user name of the account you want to connect to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiBQV.png) and click OK.
7. [Here is the installation complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LHmo.png)
8. Now double-click the folder you just created or press Enter to connect
9. Type your connection a name
10. Type your password
11. Allow plug-in
12. Here is your Google Drive.

And now it's off topic but bonus information for Total Commander

**What else can you do with Total Commander?**

1. It is an FTP tool.
2. The folder is navigator.
3. Batch name change tool. (You can change a nice day for example)
4. Unzips and zip (zip, rar, tar, arj, uc2, gz, lha, ace, tgz)
5. Selects all files with specific characters in the name
6. You can search only the extensions you want. (For example, php and css only.

If you are interested in the answer and this additional information, you can use Total Commander every day like me.

I hope that will be useful.

Answer (score -1):

FTP is an obsolete and insecure protocol, you should not use it. Servers should only run SSH, and you can use SFTP or SCP to transfer files.

For S3, there are many tools ([Python](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd), [Ruby](http://s3sync.net/wiki.html), etc) that work well.  You could also use `fuse` to "mount" S3 like a filesystem, but I don't recommend these because when they have problems, they are hard to troubleshoot.

For GDrive, there are several (I tried out one a while back and it worked, but I don't remember which one.)

Comment: Well FTP is what the control panel for my hosting(and every other hosting I ever had only has an ftp option) and still used alot. With my hosting I am on shared hosting so I don't have access to the server and can't start installing programs so that is why it would be great if I could just use ftp. Or can maybe this SFTP could be used in the same area as the ftp but does S3 have a url for it?

Answer (score -1):

[couchdrop.io](https://couchdrop.io) has an sftp gateway that is usable for this

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Please add some explanation and quotes.